Is linear momentum always conserved in absence of external forces
Consider a rod placed on a smooth horizontal table. If a ball hits its centre of mass elastically, you can just apply conservation of linear momentum and find the kinetic energy of the rod. But if it hits its end, and linear momentum is conserved, then not only does it have the translational kinetic energy it did in the previous case, but also rotational energy. This disobeys the conservation of energy hence we can conclude linear momentum of the rod will be different compared to the former case. Why is that the case? There is no external forces acting on it, then why isn't the law of linear momentum conservation not applicable?

If the ball does not transfer all of its linear momentum then it will still have some.

You should set the problem up, with masses $M$, $m$, a velocity $v$, an impact parameter $b$, and a rod $L$, and show that KE isn't conserved, because just declaring it in a sentence is not good enough.

If the collision is elastic then you will probably find that the total energy was conserved, but you haven't made that calculation in support of your argument.

@Triatticus it is an elastic collision, so by definition the energy is conserved, but the energy is split between translational and rotational kinetic energy, which implies that linear momentum isn't conserved in the normal way

Did you actually perform the calculation though, because now you have to conserve angular and linear momentum. If you actually put down your working of the problem you will see conservation of both.

@Triatticus take a ball and rod of each mass m. In the first case, the rod gets the same velocity as the ball and ball becomes stationary (since same mass), so the linear momentum is conserved and total energy = 1/2 mv². Simple enough. But now for the second case, if I apply conservation of linear momentum like i did in the first case, I have the same amount of translational energy, but I will also have rotational energy with angular momentum of the rod being equal to 24v/L (where L is the length of rod). Now where did this extra energy come from? It didn't, so linear momentum shouldnt be same

I suggest watching a video by veritasium called bullet block experiment, the only difference between what he does in the video and my question is my collision is elastic, while his was an inelastic collision between the bullet and block, which explains everything.

Both linear and angular momentum must be conserved, regardless of whether or not mechanical energy is conserved.
If impacting the rod at the end produces less linear momentum in the rod than impacting the COM then the ball must also have transferred less of its linear momentum to the rod.
Then, if it transfers less of its linear momentum, it must also transfer less of its translational KE as well, such that, assuming a perfectly elastic collision, the sum of the total KE (translational plus rotational) of the ball and rod after the collision equals the initial translational KE of the ball, for conservation of total KE.
Consider, for example, the case where the mass of the ball and rod are the same, and the collision is perfectly elastic. If the ball impacts the center of mass (COM) of the rod head on, it will stop and transfer all of its linear momentum to the rod. No angular momentum about the COM will occur.
On the other hand, if it impacts the rod some distance away from the COM of the rod, it will continue moving at some lower velocity transferring less of its linear momentum (and translational kinetic energy) to the center of mass of the rod, but now will have some angular momentum with respect to the COM that must to be transferred to the rod to conserve angular momentum. In so doing it will now give the rod rotational kinetic energy.
The sum of the translational and rotational KE of the ball and after the collision will need to equal the initial translational KE of the ball for conservation of total KE.
Hope this helps.

Why is the linear momentum transferred different?

@Yajas what happens to a moving object in a perfectly elastic  head on collision with an initially stationary object ?

depends on the mass of the resting object, if it's the same mass, then it's velocity becomes zero, if the mass is lower then it slows down, and if the mass is greater, it moves with some velocity in the opposite direction. How is this relevant to what I've asked, I haven't mentioned anything about mass being different when it hits the rod on the end, or is there a concept I'm not aware of?

@Yajas Sorry, I meant to say the masses are equal. What I was trying to get at in the case of the ball and rod is that the ball will transfer the maximum amount of linear momentum (and translational KE) to the rod if it impacts the COM, transferring less as it impacts further away. Conversely, the ball transfers zero angular momentum (and rotational KE)if it impacts the COM, while increasingly transferring angular momentum (and rotational KE) the further away the impact is from the COM, with the maximum at the ends.

@Yajas the following link demonstrates the behavior of a rod and ball relevant to your post, except it involves an inelastic collision so KE is not conserved. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yu4YnzfIRFQ

@Yajas FWIW I did an example calculation of ball impacting the end of the rod assuming mass of the ball and rod each  1 kg,  and ball with initial velocity of 10 m/s. Thus total initial KE is 50 J translational. Then, applying  conservation of linear and angular momentum, and conservation of KE (assuming elastic collision),  I obtained final total translational KE of 26J (18J ball + 8J rod COM ) and final rotational KE OF 24J.

Conservation of linear momentum always applies.  In the case of the ball hitting the center of the rod, you know by symmetry that the rod has no rotational momentum or energy.  That means that you can look at only the linear momentum and linear kinetic energy to have enough information to solve for the final state.
When the ball hits off-center, you don't have that symmetry.  The rod will have some rotational energy in the final state, and you need to include that when solving for the final state.  If you do, you'll find that your assumption

then not only does it have the translational kinetic energy it did in the previous case

will be incorrect.
In short, it's the symmetry of the first case that lets you easily solve that case.

My assumption is in line with what you're saying, it will have both rotational and translational in the second case. But the translational energy alone wouldn't be equal, or rather it shouldn't

Correct, the translational kinetic energy will be different for the two cases.
